# How to convert y4m file to yuv?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, yuv

I searched the internet and Stack Overflow, but I could not find an answer:

- Does anyone know how to convert a y4m file to yuv?

Comment: You wouldn't find this answer at Stack Overflow because it's off-topic. Stack Overflow is about programming.

Comment: I am gstreamer guy so i would do as  "gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="test.y4m" ! y4mdec ! filesink location="test.yuv""

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ffmpeg to the rescue!

A detailed description of the format is found [here](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2):

Example files can be downloaded from http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/yuv4mpeg2/

To convert the file to [YV12-format](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#YV12), do

```
$ ffmpeg -i example.y4m test.yuv
```

The first frame looks like this:

[image]